# Wordpress side bar admin menu for my custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I have created a custom post type called "Home Page" using `register_post_type` and below is my code.

```
$labels = array(
             
        'name' => __( 'Home Page'),
        'singular_name' => __( 'Home Page'),
        'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Home Page'),            
    );

$args = array(
        'label'               => __( 'Home Page'),
        'description'         => __( 'Custom Post Type'),
        'labels'              => $labels,       
        'hierarchical'        => false,
        'public'              => false,
        'show_ui'             => true,
        'show_in_menu'        => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
        'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
        'has_archive'         => false,        
        'exclude_from_search' => true,
        'publicly_queryable'  => true,
        'map_meta_cap'        => fa,
        'capabilities' => array(
            'create_posts' => 'do_not_allow',
            'delete_published_posts' => false,
            'read_post' => false,
        ),
        
        
    );
register_post_type( 'homepage', $args );
```

And I have used "Advanced Custom Fields" WordPress plugin to add custom fields to this new custom post type. These all working fine and its showing like below.

[image]

But the thing I want is, I will only have 1 record so if I click on "Home Page" on the left side bar admin menu link, it should be redirected to that particular record with something like `post.php?post=37&action=edit` in the URL.

I already know doing `'show_in_menu'        => false,` will hide the url from the left sidebar.

But how can I hide this menu and directly go to edit page for only single record which I will always have?

Can someone guide me what should I do from here on to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK Guys,

Eventually, I have found a way to implement this feature. Here is what I have done.

```
// Adding custom menu for custom post type 
function add_link_to_category_tips_n_tricks() {
    $link = 'post.php?post=39&action=edit';
    add_menu_page( 'Home Page', 'Home Page', 'edit_pages', $link, '', 'dashicons-admin-home', 8 );
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'add_link_to_category_tips_n_tricks' );
```

This will create a new custom menu and will redirect at the page where I want.

Thanks all for your support and guidance.

Answer (score 1):

if you have already made the first post:

in your `register_post_type` add these parameters:

```
'map_meta_cap' => true,
'capabilities' => array(
    'create_posts' => 'do_not_allow'
)
```

this will disable adding new posts to the post type.

And then the function to redirect the edit.php - making sure you pass the correct ID

```
function redirect_edit_screen() {
    
    $current_screen = get_current_screen();
    
    if( $current_screen->id === "edit-homepage" ) {
        wp_safe_redirect( admin_url('post.php?post=37&action=edit') );
        exit();
    }
}
add_action( 'current_screen', 'redirect_edit_screen' );
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply .. I can do this way too. But this will check everytime when we load any admin page. I have found another way to resolve or to implement this feature. Please check my answer and share your thoughts for the same. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it will be to redirect on [admin_init](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/admin_init/) hook. Check if `$_GET[post_type']` is set and equal to your custom post type and the `$pagenow` global is `edit.php`, Then simply redirect it using [wp_redirect()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_redirect/).

```
function redirect_to_edit() {

    global $pagenow;

    if ( isset($_GET['post_type']) && $_GET['post_type'] == 'homepage' && $pagenow == 'edit.php' ) {
      wp_redirect( admin_url('post.php?post=39&action=edit') );
      exit();
    }

}
add_action('admin_init', 'redirect_to_edit');
```

**I would prefer the way to** *create a new custom menu and redirect it to the page needed.*